# How do I make my program iterate only once every given time (ex 1/s)?

Tags: c, for-loop, timer, scheduled-tasks

Let's say that for example I have a for loop which is reading instructions line by line from a .txt file and what I wish to do is make the program execute those instructions once every second or so. How can I possibly do this?

Here's the code for my loop:

```
  for(j = 0; j < PC; j++) {             
    txtfilepointer = fopen(listWithTxtFilesToRead[j].name, "r");

    while (fscanf(txtfilepointer, "%c %s", &field1, field2) != EOF ) {

      // here it should be executing the given instruction every second or so...

      printf("whatever the instruction told me to do");
    }
  }
```

Please ignore the variable names, it's just for examplifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *make the program execute those instructions once every second or so*

Make it wait until the required time passed.

Assuming you want to have the program wait for one or more seconds (and you are on a POSIX system, like Linux, which brings [`sleep()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sleep.html)) you can do this like so:

```
#include <time.h> /* for time() */
#include <unistd.h> /* for sleep() */

#define SECONDS_TO_WAIT (3) 

...

  {
    time_t t = time(NULL);

    /* Instructions to execute go here. */

    while ((time(NULL) - t) < SECONDS_TO_WAIT)
    {
      sleep(1); /* Sleep (wait) for one second. */
    }
  }
```

Comment: that should do the work, thanks for the fast response!